# Consider the function space Ω, consists of all functions $\phi(x)$ that satisfy the infinite set of conditions

Tags: integration, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Consider the function space Ω, called the nuclear space, which consists of all functions $\phi(x)$ that satisfy the infinite set of conditions

$\int|\phi(x)|^2 (1+|x|)^n dx$ from -$\infty$ to $\infty$

for n = 0, 1, 2, . . . . The condition for n = 0 is precisely the one that defines H, so Ω
is a subspace of H. Show that for any $\phi(x)$ in Ω, the function 
ˆx$\phi(x) ≡ $x$\phi(x)$ is also
in Ω. This means the operator ˆx preserves Ω, even though it does not preserve all of
H.

The attempt

$\int|\phi^*(x)ˆx\phi(x)| (1+|x|)^n dx$

$\int|\phi^*(x)x \phi(x)| (1+|x|)^n dx$

$\int|x\phi^*(x)\phi(x)| (1+|x|)^n dx$

$\int|x\phi^*(x)\phi(x)| (1+|x|)^n dx$

$\int|x\phi(x)|^2 (1+|x|)^n dx$

$\int|x\phi^*(x)\phi(x)|^2 (1+|x|)^n dx$

$\int|x^2$|$|\phi(x)|^2 (1+|x|)^n dx$

If this is the correct approach, I don't know how I can show that this is finite when phi is any function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int|x\phi(x)|^{2}(1+|x|)^{n}dx&=\int|\phi(x)|^{2}|x|^{2}(1+|x|)^{n}dx\\
&\leq\int|\phi(x)|^{2}(1+|x|)^{2}(1+|x|)^{n}dx\\
&=\int|\phi(x)|^{2}(1+|x|)^{n+2}dx\\
&<\infty.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how you obtained (1+|x|)^2 in the second line? Does that "come" from (1+|x|)^n somehow? Does this have something to do with the Schwartz inequality? Many thanks again

Comment: Simply $|x|\leq(1+|x|)$ and hence $|x|^{2}\leq(1+|x|)^{2}$.